# Is it possible to set array between two limits?

Tags: android, char, character

Currently I have a char array

```
char[] charArray = valueofOutput.toCharArray();
for(int i = 0; i < charArray.length; i+=2){

}
```

I am trying to make it read up to a certain point, collect up the results and then convert them to an integer using `Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(charArray[i]));`

And then i want it to continue from where it left off. How do i do this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
char[] charArray = valueofOutput.toCharArray();

  for(int i = 0; i < charArray.length; i+=2){

char[i] = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(charArray[i]));

}
```